# Why getHeight() of a Viewgroup does not change

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout (ViewGroup).  And in my code, I have added a child view (another linear layout) to the LinearLayout.  My question is why the LinearLayout 's getHeight() return the SAME value? On the phone, I do see my child linear layout is visible and is displayed correctly. But why the getHeight() does not return me the right value?

And I have looked at the source code of add() in ViewGroup. It does call 'requestLayout()' so I expect the getHeight() of the ViewGroup does get update correctly. Am I correct?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? is your outer LinearLayout height=fill_parent or wrap_content or is it hard-coded? is your inner Layout empty?

Comment: i think you should wait a little time after the drawing of the child , and then try to get the height , and you will see the difference i think , try it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getHeight() is not updated immediately, requestLayout() requests a layout pass that happens later (it's asynchronous). You must post an event in the UI events queue to retrieve the height after the layotu pass:

```
requestLayout();
post(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // getHeight
  }
});
```